# Cleaning up before node js exits

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to do a proper clean-up when nodejs exits, when there are multiple clean-up functions from different modules to be run?

I want to close 2 different db connections, 1 websocket connection on application's exit and all these connections are in different modules.

If I add following snippet in all modules

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
   console.log('SIGTERM fired');
   process.exit(1);
});
```

Then only first module prints the log and process exits.

If I don't add `process.exit(1);`, then pressing Ctrl+C prints the all the logs but process does not exit.

Comment: Did you try `process.beforeExit(...)` event as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a disconnect function in your modules that would give callback when completed, when you received all callbacks you can exit the process.
so lets say,

you have 3 modules db1.js,db2.js and socketConnection.js , so you can have a close method that returns callback eg:

```
db1.close=function(callback){
    db.close();
    callback();
}
```

and in your main js file where you handle exit, import all 3 modules and call close method for all connections and then exit the process. eg:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
     db1.close(function(){
        db2.close(function(){
               socketConnection.close(function(){
                      process.exit(1);
               });
        });
     });
});
```

This will ensure all close function have finished execution and exit your process safely.

Comment: I do not think you can call async functions from inside SIGTERM signal handler.